# How to Handle Data Type Mismatch Exception in C

Tags: c, exception, types, mismatch

Is it possible to handle data type mismatch exceptions in C?

In C++ and other higher-level languages, the code is usually surrounded by try...catch.  However, since there is no exception handling mechanism in C, how do we handle data type mismatch exceptions?

For instance, let us assume that I have a program that requires the user to enter an integer number.  If the user hits an alphabetic character by mistake, the program crashes.  How can I take care of this in C?

Here is some sample code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void main()
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("Hello World!\n\n");
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The integer entered is %d", x);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Press any key to exit!");
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Error checking? If your program crashes on invalid input, you're simply not validating it enough.

Comment: Can someone give me an example please?  I am quite new to the C programming language.

Comment: This is not C specific at all. There's probably approx. a quarter bazillion examples of checking return values of functions available on the web.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I posted some code

Comment: @BartFriederichs - See below

Comment: @Matthew - You need to check the return value of `scanf("%d", &x);`. Read the manual page.

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you so much for your response :)  I learned C on my own through tutorials on the internet and am quite new to the language.

Comment: @Matthew - For any function it is a good idea to get acquainted with the manual pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are using `scanf` to handle input. the program should not crash. You need to read the manual page for [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and in the section return values it tells you that the function returns the number of items matched. You compare this number with what is expected. If they differ you take the appropriate action.

**EDIT**

Some  code for Matthew and Bart:

```
int i;

if (scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
{
    printf("You have entered %d\n", i);
}
else
{
    printf("You have entered an invalid number\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding code to what @EdHeal rightly says above . 
Sample Illustrative code :

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

```
int num;
int ret;

printf("Enter a number\n");
ret=scanf("%d",&num);
/* For better clarity From the man page 
 Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure */
printf("Number of items assigned %d",ret);
printf("The input number is %d",num);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

So here for your simplicty see the return value of the scanf statment . Upon success i.e when it reads an integer it returns 1 . In case of strings it reads 0 .

Sample Output 
a ) Input an integer

```
Enter a number
68
Number of bytes read 1
The input number is 68
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
```

b) Input a string

```
Enter a number
yiy idfd
Number of bytes read 0
The input number is 2665608
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4s)
```

Comment: This line is incorrect `printf("Number of bytes read %d",ret);` It is the number of items in the format string as demonstrated by your output.

Comment: @EdHeal Yup ! wrote in a hurry . Thanks for pointing it out . !

Answer (score 1):

Several options for data input:

You can use scanf as mentioned above, but i also recommend reading man pages about getopt, getoptlong

As for validating you can try regcomp, regexec, regerror, regfree. For example :

```
   const char* pattern = "^[\\+,-]*[0-9]*$";
   regex_t regex;
   int reti;
   reti = regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
   if(reti){
   printf("error");
   exit(1);
   }
   reti = regexec(&regex, "34567", 0, NULL, 0);
   if(reti == 0) {
   printf("String matches pattern.");
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

C uses return values and the `errno` global to indicate if anything went wrong or not. So, in your case, let's assume (since you didn't provide any code), you are using [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to translate a string into an integer:

```
 char *s = "1234";
 int number;
 number = strtol(s, NULL, 10);
```

If number is `0` and `errno` is set, something went wrong.

All functions in C work in this way. To make your code more robust, read strings instead of numbers and convert them.

In fact, there is a lot to be found on exceptions and return codes. In my opinion, exceptions should be used for stuff that is exceptional. And incorrect data input is not exceptional (it is more a rule actually ;-)), so there should be no exception be thrown when it connect convert. Perhaps this is the reason C# also has a `TryParse` method.

Comment: So 0 is no longer an integer?!

Comment: the -1 is not from me, but `atoi` is really a bad example

Comment: @JensGustedt would `strtol` be better? The point was to use return codes instead of exceptions.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, sure. `strtol` has a precise way of telling you when things go wrong. `atoi` hasn't since `0` is a valid input.

Comment: @JensGustedt how exactly, I don't see any difference in the docs. It seems to use errno. I updated my answer.

Comment: From the man page: the atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as

           strtol(nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);

       except that atoi() does not detect errors.